# Substitute for SHGetFileInfoW function

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm having problem with SHGetFileInfoW function I'm using.

It's a quite slow and first read on startup (Initialization) consumes 100ms.

In MSDN stays that it should be read from thread, not the main thread because it can stuck process.

I want to use some other function, if there is any, in order to read Icons.

Another thing. How is possible to read big icons, currently I can read up to 32x32 (SHGFI_LARGEICON)

Thanks!

Actual code:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadIcons;
var
  Info:     TShFileInfo;
  Icon:     TIcon;
  Flags:    UINT;
  FileName: PAnsiChar;

begin
  FileName := '.txt';
  Flags := SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES or SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_LARGEICON;
  Icon := TIcon.Create;
  try
    SHGetFileInfo(FileName, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, Info,
      SizeOf(Info), Flags);
    Icon.Handle := Info.hIcon;
    Image1.Picture.Assign(Icon);
    Image1.Refresh;
  finally
    DestroyIcon(Info.hIcon);
    Icon.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just run it in a thread. Or don't read all the icons at startup, just read them on demand. AsyncCalls would get the job done pretty easily.

Comment: Problem is in initial reading. When I read first icon I spend 80+ms. When I read next 20 icons I consume another 20ms.
I'm reading it currently in AsyncCalls (we discussed about it in the other topic) and it runs good, but I would like to speed it up additionally cause speed is essential form my app.

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: I've added it. First time when I call this function it consumes over 300ms on E8400 CPU (on another CPU, I7-2600K it consumes "only" 100ms (!!) ). Each next time when I try to read info it consumes about 1ms, and less then 1ms on faster CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find the `DefaultIcon` for a given file extension from the Registry and use `ExtractIconEx`. [Here is an example](http://www.awitness.org/delphi_pascal_tutorial/source4/registry_associated_applications.html)

I don't know if it's faster than `SHGetFileInfo`

**EDIT:**

I have extracted (from the sample) the part which gets the ICON from the Extension. 
It actually works very fast. could be optimized more.
(I modified the code a bit):

```
// find the icon for a certain file extension in the registry
function TForm1.RegistryIconExtraction(Extension : string): integer;
var
    RegKey : TRegistry;
    IconPos : integer;
    AssocAppInfo : string;
    ExtractPath, FileName : string;
    IconHandle, PLargeIcon, PSmallIcon : HICON;
    AnIcon : TIcon;

begin
  Result := 0; // default icon

  if Extension[1] <> '.' then Extension := '.' + Extension;

  RegKey := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ);
  try
    // KEY_QUERY_VALUE grants permission to query subkey data.
    RegKey.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT; // set folder for icon info lookup
    if RegKey.OpenKeyReadOnly(Extension) then // extension key exists?
    try
      AssocAppInfo := RegKey.ReadString('');  // read app key
      RegKey.CloseKey;
    except
      Exit;
    end;
    if ((AssocAppInfo <> '') and  // app key and icon info exists?
      (RegKey.OpenKeyReadOnly(AssocAppInfo + '\DefaultIcon'))) then
    try
      ExtractPath := RegKey.ReadString(''); // icon path
      RegKey.CloseKey;
    except
       Exit;
    end;
  finally
    RegKey.Free;
  end;

  // IconPos after comma in key  ie: C:\Program Files\Winzip\Winzip.Exe,0
  // did we get a key for icon, does IconPos exist after comma seperator?
  If ((ExtractPath <> '') and (pos(',', ExtractPath) <> 0)) then
  begin

    // Filename in registry key is before the comma seperator
    FileName := Copy(ExtractPath, 1, Pos(',', ExtractPath) - 1);
    // extract the icon Index from after the comma in the ExtractPath string
    try
      IconPos := StrToInt(copy(ExtractPath, Pos(',', ExtractPath) + 1,
        Length(ExtractPath) - Pos(',', ExtractPath) + 1));
    except
      Exit;
    end;

    IconHandle := ExtractIconEx(PChar(FileName), IconPos, PLargeIcon, PSmallIcon, 1);

    If (PLargeIcon <> 0) then
    begin
      AnIcon := TIcon.Create;
      AnIcon.Handle := PLargeIcon;

      Image1.Picture.Assign(AnIcon);
      Image1.Refresh;

      AnIcon.Free;
    end;

    DestroyIcon(PLargeIcon);
    DestroyIcon(PSmallIcon);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t1, t2: DWORD;
begin
  t1 := GetTickCount;
  RegistryIconExtraction('.txt');
  t2 := GetTickCount;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(t2-t1));
end;
```

**EDIT2:** The sample code is now Vista/Win7 UAC compliant.

Comment: Nope. This is not a solution of what I need. this function extracts icons from exe or dll, I doesn't work with extensions.

Comment: Have you tried this on Win7 with UAC turned present? In order to read HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT regular you need to elevate user privileges to Admin. This is the problem why I can't read directly from registry.

Otherwise this would be a finite solution.

Comment: I have tested it on XP (no UAC). There should be no problem to read the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT if you use: `TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ)` and `OpenKeyReadOnly`

Comment: There is no prob on XP - but on Win7 with UAC I can't read that section of reg without elevating user to admin. I have that part in my program, COM object that I elevate but I can't do that on startup; cause it's essential for me to have max speed.

Comment: There is no need to elevate the user on Win7 with UAC in order to read HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. read my previous comment again... [to confirm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066818/cannot-read-from-registry-hkey-classes-root-if-not-running-in-administrator-mo)